# Protection for actors when filming sex scenes in mainstream movies

Tags: film-techniques

In an interview someone mentioned a protection used when filming scenes featuring simulated sex for mainstream movies. Is there an image of such a contraption? I'm curious how this works.

Comment: I've merged both my comments into an answer. Whatever anyone thinks of the names; that's what they're called.

Answer (score 9):

The male item of costume is called, rather unceremoniously, a cock sock. The female, a snatch patch.
Like it or lump it, that's what they're called.

Basically, a flesh-coloured piece of rather thick material, more like a wash-leather than woven material. The male version is a simple bag with an elastic pull-tie at the top. The female version is flat-ish and is stuck on with adhesive. [I've never actually seen one of these up close - it's not something you really ask about].
I don't think pictures or detailed fitting instructions would be necessary or quite appropriate.

These days due to fashion, quite often a [merkin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkin) is added, especially for period drama, to give that authentic look.

Anecdotally, though cock socks come in two sizes, costume will always offer the large. You can have a medium if you ask. They don't make small.

If anyone needs citation further than, *"I've worn one"* ;) then see [Cosmopolitan - 10 Surprising Facts About How Hollywood Sex Scenes Really Get Made](https://www.cosmopolitan.com/entertainment/movies/a8071969/sex-scenes-secrets/)

This is a bag of marbles. Use your imagination.

[image]

Unsurprisingly, if you google 'cock sock' you will struggle to find the simple flesh-coloured ones used for filming. You will find, errmm… more ornate ones, usually being worn. You've been warned.

Comment: The truth nobody likes to talk around...